# Django combining data from separate HTML forms to Django View

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a django application that needs to return post.request data from two separate parts (products and entries). At the moment, the template is setup as two separate HTML forms and what I need to do is to combine it into one. Therefore upon clicking the button the values for product ID and entry quantity are both passed to the view. I can't work out how to do this so would appreciate any help.

HTML Template File:

```
<body>
 {% for product in products %}
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ product.name }}
    <br/>
    {{ product.id }}
    <input type="hidden" name='product_id' value='{{ product.id }}'>
    <button>Product Object and ID</button>
</form>
{% endfor %}
{% for cart in my_carts_current_entries %}
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <br/>
    <input type="hidden" name='entry_quantity' value='{{ cart.quantity }}'>
    <button>Entry Quantity</button>
</form>
{% endfor %}


</body>
```

Views.py

```
def test_view(request):
    cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
    my_carts_current_entries = Entry.objects.filter(cart=cart_obj)
    products = Product.objects.all()

    if request.POST:
        product_id = request.POST.get('product_id')
        print(product_id)

        product_obj = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
        print(product_obj)

        entry_quantity = request.POST.get('entry_quantity')
        print(entry_quantity)
        # Entry.objects.create(cart=cart_obj, product=product_obj, quantity=entry_quantity)
    return render(request, 'carts/test.html', {'cart_obj': cart_obj, 'my_carts_current_entries': my_carts_current_entries,
                                              'products': products})
```

Comment: you should probably use ajax to constuct a post object that is sane ... otherwise make all your input's `name="thing1[]"` with the squarebrackets to allow you to send more than one item with the same name

Comment: Sorry didn't understand the second point - can you elaborate? Ajax is not an option at this point

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="POST">
{% for product in products %}
<input type="hidden" name='product_id[]' value='{{ product.id }}'>
{% endfor %}
{% for cart in my_carts_current_entries %}
<input type="hidden" name='entry_quantity[]' value='{{ cart.quantity }}'>
{% endfor %}
<button>Submit</button>
</form>
```